# Magento Update 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1

Tags: upgrade

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                  
  Package is not installed: magento/project-community-edition-2.4.3.0-patch1  
                                                                              

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I got this error after update the site from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1.
I run this command

```
composer require  magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 --no-update
composer update
```

Please let me know how to fix this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found the solution.
I removed the vertex modules in 2.4.2 and it worked well.
From 2.4.3 the vertex modules are required module.
So I have to add them from 2.4.3 again.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, make sure you are using correct require

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 --no-update
```

for some reason they are using `require-commerce`

Comment: require-commerce not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following require commands

Remove composer.lock file

```
rm rf composer.lock
```

Update all dependencies

```
composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch ~7.11.0 --no-update
composer require laminas/laminas-serializer ^2.11 --no-update
composer require magento/framework 103.0.3-p1 --no-update
composer require magento/module-elasticsearch 101.0.3 --no-update
composer require ramsey/uuid ~4 --no-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 --no-update
```

Run composer update

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it's not working
It's displaying same error.
Package is not installed: magento/project-community-edition-2.4.3.0-patch1

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please recheck